# Target button hover using Id + Label and for in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a series of buttons on a page and I want to target their hover functionality each individually, but if I try adding `:hover` to this it does not work.

Is there a way to get this to work?

```css
input.chk-btn+label[for=recent-check] {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red !important;
}

input.chk-btn+label[for=recent-check]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="chk-btn" id="recent-check" type="checkbox">
<label class="btn btn-success text-uppercase m-b-xs sort-button" for="recent-check">Recent
<span class="glyphicon"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Are you changing `red` to ... `red` on hover?

Comment: As the hover state is exactly the same as the non-hovered state, you need to specify what exactly isn't working; and how you can tell it's not working. Also, using `!important` in your CSS property-declarations usually indicates a problem with specificity or a misunderstanding of the cascade; it's not *always* a problem, but more often than not it is. I'm voting to close because, as yet, you haven't explained your problem.

Comment: Are you wanting the checkbox to change on hover?

Answer (score 1):

```css
input.chk-btn + label[for=recent-check]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="chk-btn" id="recent-check" type="checkbox">
<label class="btn btn-success text-uppercase m-b-xs sort-button" for="recent-check">Recent
<span class="glyphicon"></span>
</label>
```

The above code works for me!

If your question is to ensure that the background changes colour on hover of the checkbox instead of the label you need to move the hover selector to after the checkbox selector not the label selector.

```css
input.chk-btn:hover + label[for=recent-check] {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="chk-btn" id="recent-check" type="checkbox">
<label class="btn btn-success text-uppercase m-b-xs sort-button" for="recent-check">Recent
<span class="glyphicon"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Feel free to edit. I'm not sure why someone downvoted. Downvoter, care to comment on why?